# Problem With DB Connection in PHP with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Using the following to connect to a MySQL server while using Xampp.

```
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

$mysql_db = 'a_database';

if(mysqli_connect('$mysql_host','$mysql_user','$mysql_pass') || !mysqli_select_db($mysql_db)) {
    die ('could not connect');
}

?>
```

But I received the following errors:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\connect.inc.php
> on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\connect.inc.php on line 8
>
> Warning:
> mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php\connect.inc.php on line 8 could not connect

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the db connection in `mysqli_select_db`

Try this instead!

```
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

$mysql_db = 'a_database';

$db = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// you select db with the mysql connection variable
mysqli_select_db($db, $mysql_db);
```

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes **do not** interpolate, they send in *literal* text, including the `$`, which is not what you want.

You shouldn't be enquoting these values anyway, just put them in as-is:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)
```

It's a very common anti-pattern to see things like `"$x"` in PHP code, something that presumably bubbles over from shell scripting where it can be necessary. In PHP it isn't, and often causes trouble as it has here.

Don't forget to *save your database connection into a variable* or it'll be thrown out before you can use it.

Another thing to note is that the object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

The proper way to use `mysqli` is:

```
$db = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)
```

Where that operates exactly the same except that it's far more minimal, like as in:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
```

Instead of the far more verbose:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "...")
```

Where that gets even more verbose for statement manipulation functions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it is also solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

A simple  Object Oriented style connection string can do the magic

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","a_database");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
?>
```